# 'Fire' keypress in zombiejs

Tags: keypress, zombie.js

I need some help.  I am about to hit the wall trying to get Phantom to work.  It just sporadically stops working and something that should work, doesn't.  It has been so frustrating.  I got zombiejs up and running in a 10th of the time doing what I need, apart from simulating a keypress.  I can't figure out the syntax for firing key presses.  Their API has the following:

```
browser.fire(name, target, calback?)

Fires a DOM event. You can use this to simulate a DOM event, e.g. clicking a link or clicking the mouse. These events will bubble up and can be cancelled.
```

If someone has an example, I won't have to look at Phantom again.  At least until they make their API a lot easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted a solution for this in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/275#issuecomment-5540968):

```
zombie.Browser.prototype.keyUp = function(targetSelector, keyCode) {
  var event = this.window.document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent('keyup', true, true);
  event.which = keyCode;
  var target = this.window.document.querySelector(targetSelector);
  target && target.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```